# Gridview column that changes when required (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to have a GridView listing all invoices of an account. Each account can have a PDF generated for that account, which isn't done instantly - so I need a gridview column to update the user of the progress of this conversion - i.e. 'In Progress'.

Then, when the conversion is done the cell's text should change to a hyperlink to the PDF file.

I know it's a very vague question in regards to monitoring the state of the PDF, but I'd just like to know if AJAX would be a solution and what controls I would use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... So there's a gridview with several rows (accounts), and each account may have its Pdf state changed at any time, and the link cell should be refreshed immediately (upon a Pdf state change)?

Try searching for "web methods" + "web services" + "asynchronous" and check if it's what you are looking for.

If you can, using a control like Telerik's RadControls Grid, which has Webservice binding, can do the work for you, continuously refreshing the data as it changes: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/aspajaxgridapplication/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid